# Code fails to link with report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

My code fails to link to my report. I need to pass the parameter "T-ID" to the report but for some reason I can't get any data when I click the button.

In Crystal Reports I can get data after inputting the parameter, but it fails to generate when run from my program. How can I fix this?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument test = new ReportDocument();
    test.Load(Server.MapPath("On Job Training 1.rpt"));
    test.SetParameterValue("T-ID", TextBox1.Text);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = test;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = test;
}
```

Comment: Use `On Job Training 1 test = new On Job Training 1();` Your SetParameterValue is correct and all your code, so try that and tell me if it works

Comment: On Job Training 1 test = new On Job Training 1();
add this to my source code?

Comment: Replace `ReportDocument test = new ReportDocument();
    test.Load(Server.MapPath("On Job Training 1.rpt"));`  by `Job Training 1 test = new On Job Training1();`  ( => the name of your .rpt class)